# PInvoke PFCreateInterface C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am attempting to pinvoke PFCreateInterface in C# for a packet filtering app. However, the example on pinvoke.net seems inadequately documented. For starters, once StartPacketFilter() in main is called, how can i remove the packet filter programatically without closing the app? Also, i'm also quite confused about the format of the packet string. 
I.e `hostsToBlock[0] = "67.77.87.97,255.255.255.255,0";    //blocks all traffic on any port to/from 67.77.87.97`

How would i go about blocking a remote port of 6980 across all ips?

The pinvoke codes are as follows :

```
/// <summary>
/// IP packet filter management wrapper for Iphlpapi.dll (Win 2000/XP)
/// </summary>
/// 
public class IpPacketFilter
{
    [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", EntryPoint = "PfBindInterfaceToIPAddress")]
    public static extern int PfBindInterfaceToIPAddress(
                                    IntPtr Interface_handle,
                                    PFADDRESSTYPE pfatType,
                                    ref int ip_address
                                    );


    [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", EntryPoint = "PfCreateInterface")]
    public static extern int PfCreateInterface(
                                    int dwName,
                                    PFFORWARD_ACTION inAction,
                                    PFFORWARD_ACTION outAction,
                                    bool UseLog,
                                    bool MustBeUnique,
                                    ref IntPtr ppInterface
                                    );

    //////


    ////

    [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", EntryPoint = "PfAddFiltersToInterface")]
    public static extern int PfAddFiltersToInterface(
                                    IntPtr interface_handle,
                                    int cInFilters,
                                    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Struct)] 
                                    ref PPF_FILTER_DESCRIPTOR pfiltIn,
                                    int cOutFilters,
                                    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
                                    ref PPF_FILTER_DESCRIPTOR pfiltOut,
                                    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
                                     ref PPF_FILTER_DESCRIPTOR pfHandle
                                    );

}


 public unsafe struct PPF_FILTER_DESCRIPTOR
{
    public FILTER_FLAGS dwFilterFlags;
    public int dwRule;
    public PFADDRESSTYPE pfatType;

    public int* SrcAddr;
    public int* SrcMask;
    public int* DstAddr;
    public int* DstMask;

    public PROTOCOL dwProtocol;
    public int fLateBound;
    public int wSrcPort;
    public int wDstPort;
    public int wSrcPortHighRange;
    public int wDstPortHighRange;
}
public enum PFFORWARD_ACTION : int
{
    PF_ACTION_FORWARD = 0,
    PF_ACTION_DROP
}

public enum PFADDRESSTYPE : int
{
    PF_IPV4,
    PF_IPV6
}
public  enum PROTOCOL : int
{
    ANY = 0x00,
    ICMP = 0x01,
    TCP = 0x06,
    UDP = 0x11
}

public  enum FILTER_FLAGS : int
{
    FD_FLAGS = 0x1
}
```

class Program
{

```
internal const int FALSE = 0;
internal const int TRUE = 1;


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] hostsToBlock = new string[2];
    hostsToBlock[0] = "67.77.87.97,255.255.255.255,0";    //blocks all traffic on any port to/from 67.77.87.97
    hostsToBlock[1] = "0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0,29000";        //blocks all traffic on port 29000, in and out
    StartPacketFilter(hostsToBlock);
}

internal static int lIpFromString(string sIpAddress)
{
    int lIp = 0;
    try
    {
        string[] octets = sIpAddress.Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        if (octets.Length != 4)
            return 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            lIp |= (int.Parse(octets[i]) << (i * 8));
    }
    catch { }
    return lIp;
}

internal static string[] GetLocalIpAddresses()
{
    IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    string[] localIpAddresses = new string[host.AddressList.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < host.AddressList.Length; i++)
    {
        localIpAddresses[i] = host.AddressList[i].ToString();
    }
    return localIpAddresses;
}

internal static bool StartPacketFilter(string[] hosts)
{
    string[] localIpAddresses = GetLocalIpAddresses();
    if (localIpAddresses == null)
        return false;

    foreach (string localAddress in localIpAddresses)
    {
        int result;
        IntPtr interfaceHandle = new IntPtr();

        //convert the string IP to an unsigned int for p/invoke
        int lLocalIp = lIpFromString(localAddress);

        //create a filter interface in the tcp/ip stack
        result = IpPacketFilter.PfCreateInterface(0, PFFORWARD_ACTION.PF_ACTION_FORWARD, PFFORWARD_ACTION.PF_ACTION_FORWARD, false, true, ref interfaceHandle);
        if (result != 0)
            return false;

        //bind interface to an ip address
        result = IpPacketFilter.PfBindInterfaceToIPAddress(interfaceHandle, PFADDRESSTYPE.PF_IPV4, ref lLocalIp);
        if (result != 0)
            return false;

        foreach (string targetHost in hosts)
        {
            IntPtr filterHandle = new IntPtr();
            string[] hostDetail = targetHost.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (hostDetail != null && hostDetail.Length == 3)
            {
                //build the filter structure
                PPF_FILTER_DESCRIPTOR filter = new PPF_FILTER_DESCRIPTOR();
                filter.dwFilterFlags = FILTER_FLAGS.FD_FLAGS;
                filter.dwRule = FALSE;
                filter.pfatType = PFADDRESSTYPE.PF_IPV4;
                filter.dwProtocol = PROTOCOL.TCP;

                int iSrcAddr = lLocalIp;
                int iSrcMask = lIpFromString("255.255.255.255");
                filter.wSrcPort = 0;
                filter.wSrcPortHighRange = 0;

                int iDstAddr = lIpFromString(hostDetail[0]);
                int iDstMask = lIpFromString(hostDetail[1]);
                filter.wDstPort = int.Parse(hostDetail[2]);
                filter.wDstPortHighRange = int.Parse(hostDetail[2]);

                unsafe
                {
                    filter.SrcAddr = &iSrcAddr;
                    filter.DstAddr = &iDstAddr;
                    filter.SrcMask = &iSrcMask;
                    filter.DstMask = &iDstMask;
                }
                // add filter to interface (both inbound and outbound)
                result = IpPacketFilter.PfAddFiltersToInterface(interfaceHandle, 1, ref filter, 1, ref filter, ref filter);

                if (result != 0)
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: This seems to have less to do with pinvoke and more to do with not understanding PFCreateInterface. Read up on the documentation, figure out how it works, and THEN use pinvoke. Don't rely on pinvoke documentation to help you, all it tells you how to do is CALL it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376646(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick search, I found this: [PfRemoveFiltersFromInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376656%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). This seems to do exactly what your asking for.